# Unable to deactivate touchpad in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04. Everything seems to be fine except that I cannot disable my touchpad since I use a wireless mouse.

[image: Mouse & Touchpad settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gnome extension "TouchPad" which allows you to do it. You have to play a bit with "Indicator Preferences". However is not very stable... If you detach an external mouse is enabling the touchpad if you reattach a mouse then it disables it. However in some cases it doesn't really disable the touchpad and you have to change the mode or take in/out the mouse 2-3 times before it works again!!!

I hope they will find a solution to it soon....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)